# Comparing two DATETIME columns in SQL

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I have two datetime columns:

```
StartDate : 2019-07-01 13:30:00.000
AdmitDate : 2019-07-01 00:00:00.000
```

I want to select all rows that have the same date (excluding the time, seconds, etc).

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 as t1
    INNER JOIN table2 as t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t1.startdate >= t2.admitdate or t1.startdate <= t2.admitdate
```

However, this won't work because one of the columns has hours, minutes and seconds. How to fix this? Again, I just want the date, not time.

Comment: `convert(date,t1.startdate) = convert(date,t2.admitdate)` but that may not perform too well.

Comment: Yeah, one of them did. Already accepted the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is simpler to convert the columns in **Date**

it depends if both columns are datetime or one is date

```
SELECT Table1.Id,Table1.Startdate
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Id = Table2.Id
where (cast(Table1.Startdate as date))=(cast(Table2.AdmitDateTime as date))


SELECT Table1.Id,Table1.Startdate 
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Id = Table2.Id
where (cast(Table1.Startdate as date))=Table2.AdmitDate
```

[Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d19a2/9)

Answer (score 1):

How about using [DATEDIFF()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)?

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 as t1
INNER JOIN table2 as t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, t1.startdate, t2.admitdate) = 0
```